# Not able to run gremlin-server on mac due to gremlin.sh failure

Tags: macos, groovy, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm new to Gremlin / Java. I downloaded [gremlin-server](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/tinkerpop/3.6.0/apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.6.0-bin.zip) on my mac (macOS Monterey , Version 12.3.1).
Here's Java version:

```
$ java --version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
java 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and while running `./bin/gremlin.sh` running into following error. Any ideas? thanks.

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
Exception in thread "main" BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script1.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 62
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:969)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:642)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:401)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.access$300(GroovyClassLoader.java:89)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:341)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$5.provide(GroovyClassLoader.java:338)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.ConcurrentCommonCache.getAndPut(ConcurrentCommonCache.java:147)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:336)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:546)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:442)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:481)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:452)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackagesAndClassesFromJigsaw(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.getPackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.initializePackages(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.PackageHelperImpl.<init>(PackageHelperImpl.groovy:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:112)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.<init>(Groovysh.groovy:140)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.<init>(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:257)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:107)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:265)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:576)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findDecompiled(ClassNodeResolver.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.tryAsLoaderClassOrScript(ClassNodeResolver.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.findClassNode(ClassNodeResolver.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ClassNodeResolver.resolveName(ClassNodeResolver.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveToOuter(ResolveVisitor.java:853)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:467)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:629)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:612)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolveFromDefaultImports(ResolveVisitor.java:586)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:465)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.resolve(ResolveVisitor.java:428)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformVariableExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:871)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:879)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:888)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1264)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:879)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformDeclarationExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1291)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1553)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1103)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1465)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$13.call(CompilationUnit.java:700)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:965)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: Did you try changing java_home to use Java11 or Java8 ?

Comment: sweet, that works. I didn't have jdk11 , so I  had to open an account with oracle and download older version and then change JAVA_HOME  to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.15.jdk/Contents/Home/` to get it to work. thanks.

Comment: @Anil_M Are you saying that you got `Unsupported class file major version 62` when you runt he script with Java 18 but it works when you run with Java 11?

Comment: Precisely, I didn't check higher versions (11+) to check which one actually breaks it. Might try out later when I have more time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer based on the discussion above in case others find this question.

As of time of writing (2022-08-23), Apache TinkerPop supports the Java 8 and Java 11 JDK/JRE, and can be built and run using either. Due to cross dependencies on other libraries that have not yet moved beyond Java 8/11, TinkerPop is not able to move up either. For now you need to use either Java 8 or Java 11.

Specifically on a Mac, you will need to set `JAVA_HOME` to  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.15.jdk/Contents/Home/`